# Is time.process_time() a better measure for performance than time.time()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time

I'm fairly new to python (and CS in general), and I've been reading some docs regarding the "time" library in python. There are quite a lot of time measuring methods, and I'm trying to find the most suitable one that will enable me to compare the performance of 2 versions of an algorithm.

I understand that time.time() is wall time, and time.process_time() is either user-cpu time or system-cpu time (I'm not quite sure), but which one of these two would be a better (more accurate) measure of performance?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `time.perf_counter()` as it is the recommended function for this kind of tasks (it auto selects the method with highest precision available).

It returns a float, that means just nothing on its own (unlike the result of `time.time()`), but computing the difference between two `time.perf_counter()`'s measurements tells you how much time elapsed.

For more info, read the [`time.perf_counter()`'s docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter).